# Trying to align my tab in the middle of the page and have captions if possible?

Tags: html, css, alignment, bootstrap-4

I made a tab which has 3 images as buttons. I can't seem to align it in the middle so I just margin-ed it over which I know is the incorrect way to do it. Also, I am trying to have captions underneath it which describe what the buttons are but I also did that separately and "manually" which again I know is incorrect but I just wanted to see how things will look aesthetically. Can I attach the captions to the buttons somehow? Also, If its possible I would love to get spaces about 50px between each button in my tab but I can't seem to figure that out either.

I am using bootstrap in a very unprofessional way to align stuff and need clarification or a correct way of aligning things. I will be posting my code and a picture of what I am talking about. Thank you!

[Here is the output I have but it is all done manually using margin and bootstrap, when the computer screen is made smaller and bigger it starts looking very messy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZIFd.png)

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.tab {
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border-color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 35px;
  tab-spacing: 30px;
  color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
}

.resumeicon {
  width: 253px;
}

.coverlettericon {
  width: 250px;
}

.interviewicon {
  width: 250px;
}

.ressettings {
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: dimgrey;
  text-align: center;
}

.coversettings {
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: dimgrey;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.intsettings {
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: dimgrey;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.hint {
  font-family: 'Coiny', Serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: navy;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin: 0px 150px 0px 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="hint">Looks through Resumés, Cover Letters, and Interview Questions in the field you chose...</div>

  <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE RESUME/COVER LETTER/INTERVIEW ICONS START -->

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Resume')"><img class="resumeicon" src="/Users/mtaslagyan/Desktop/resumania/images/resumeicon.PNG"></button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'CoverLetter')"><img class="coverlettericon" src="/Users/mtaslagyan/Desktop/resumania/images/coverlettericon.PNG"></button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Interview')"><img class="interviewicon" src="/Users/mtaslagyan/Desktop/resumania/images/interviewicon.PNG"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-2 ressettings" align="center">Resumé</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 coversettings" align="center">Cover Letter</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 intsettings" align="center">Interview Questions</div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know a lot of it is pretty unprofessional but I just wanted to show what I want the output to look like, is there a way to make it like this more efficiently and professionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. It is unprofessional way. You are writing so much your own custom css. The purpose of Bootstrap is basically to reduce load of writing own css. Bootstrap does lot for you in every screen type. When you are using bootstrap, it means there should be as much small css as possible.

You should use as follows:

```
<div class="box">
        <div class="hint">Looks through Resumés, Cover Letters, and Interview Questions in the field you chose...</div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3" style="text-align:center;">
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Resume')"><img class="resumeicon iconimage" src="/Users/mtaslagyan/Desktop/resumania/images/resumeicon.PNG"></button>
                  <label style="caption-style">Resume</label>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3" style="text-align:center;">
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'CoverLetter')"><img class="coverlettericon iconimage" src="/Users/mtaslagyan/Desktop/resumania/images/coverlettericon.PNG"></button>
                    <label style="caption-style">Cover Letter</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3" style="text-align:center;">
                   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Interview')"><img class="interviewicon iconimage" src="/Users/mtaslagyan/Desktop/resumania/images/interviewicon.PNG"></button>
                    <label style="caption-style">Interview Questions</label>
                </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only this much html, you should use, and now, following is the css, which is very small:

```
.hint{
    font-family: 'Coiny', Serif;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
    color:navy;
    padding-top:60px;
    margin:0px 150px 0px 150px;
}

.iconimage{
  width:250px;
  }

  .caption-style{
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: dimgrey;
  text-align: center;
   }
```

Generally, style needs to be used for your text styles, because bootstrap has his own font styles for text/caption, you can use your css just for text font styles.

For image also, I think we don't need width, because image will cover whole 100% width in 3-parts. If image does not cover whole width in div class "col-lg-3", then prefer to use `width:100%` over `width:250px`